# Cmd.exe and command.com - special characters on windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command

When I start cmd.exe on windows XP and do this:

1. `łłłłąłąłłł [enter]`
2. `command.com [enter]`
3. `asdfgąłś [enter]`
4. `exit [enter]`
5. `łąśś [enter]`

Everything works as intended. But when I do the same thing on windows 7, this is what happens:

1. `łłłłąłąłłł [enter]`
2. `command.com [enter]`
3. `asdfg [enter]` //ąłś no longer available
4. `exit [enter]`
5. `lass [enter]` //łąśś appears as lass, from now on cmd.exe has no special characters available.

Does anyone know what is happening here? Why win7 behaves in this strange way? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Foreign characters need certain code pages using `chcp` command or they could use unicode.

A solution will depend on the exact nature of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly handle this characters, you need a specific pagecode. You can test which pagecode it is with `chcp` command.

If you start `command.com` (the 16bit DOS command processor) that pagecode can change, and when you exit from `command.com` the pagecode will not be the same. Try

```
chcp [enter]
command.com [enter]
chcp [enter]
chcp [enter]
exit [enter]
chcp [enter]
```